# redux: set state in leaf node of large state tree

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have an Immutable object that holds other Immutable objects, and the redux state tree is set to be an instance of the topmost object:

`records.js`:

```
const TypeC = newRecord({
    content: null
})

const TypeB = newRecord({
    typeC: new TypeC;
})

export const TypeA = newRecord({
    typeB: new TypeB;
})
```

`reducer.js`:

```
import {
    TypeA,
} from './records';
import types from './types';

const applicationReducer = (state = new TypeA(), action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    ...    
    }
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

My question is: how do I write reducer code to change the `content` field in TypeC? I've tried something like

```
CASE types.UPDATECONTENT: {
    return state.get('typeB').get('typeC').set('content', "new content")
}
```

but this seems to only return the `TypeC` segment of my state tree, when I need the entire tree from root.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for nested objects explained here:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

`state.get('typeB').get('typeC').set('content', "new content")` goes down the tree and modifies the attribute "content" of typeC. But since immutable is *immutable*, it does not modify anything, it returns a new record which has the updated value (!). The things between `state` and 'typeC' are not touched. Furthermore, `set` returns the newly created record, so you effectively overwrite `state` with the updated `typeC`.

An easy way to update nested objects is using the "deep persistent changes" that are named `<operation>In`, e.g. [`setIn`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn). It takes care of creating updated intermediate objects too.

TL/DR:

```
CASE types.UPDATECONTENT: {
  return state.setIn(['typeB', 'typeC','content'], "new content");
}
```